# Highchart: Area chart to display On/Off status with hours

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create an area chart which will output the status of the internet link. It is pretty straightforward. I have the values 0 - down 1 - on and the datetime of when the link was down and when it is on, so I need to plot when the link was of and on.

I'm having a problem with the following data scenario:

```
status         firstcheck                 lastcheck
0              2014-03-11 08:52:27.287    2014-03-11 08:56:13.630
1              2014-03-11 08:56:13.637    2014-03-11 09:20:05.537
0              2014-03-11 09:20:05.540    2014-03-11 09:23:52.190
1              2014-03-11 09:23:52.193    2014-03-11 17:10:52.213
```

This is the jsfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/ExNqk/3/

What I want is, the first check was off from 08:52:27 - 08:56:13.630 and then was up on 08:56:13 - 09:20:05. The problem is, if you see the jsfiddle, the Offline part of the chart is with the online part.

Tried to be clear but tell me if you don't understand what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up solving this myself. I removed the second series and put all the values on a single one. In this way it gave me the effect that I wanted. I also changed the colors for the negative values to emphasise when the connection was down. Here's a final jsfiddle for future references: http://jsfiddle.net/ExNqk/5/